# request.query_params parsed incorrectly

Tags: django

Django request.query_params returns an incorrectly formatted QueryDict. For example, if the query parameters read:

```
example_param=[{"id":"f8","example_action":"kill"}]
```

request.query_params returns:

```
<QueryDict: {'example_param': ['[{"id":"f8", "example_action": "kill"}]']}>
```

Noting example_param was parsed as a list containing a string, which is not correct.

How do I return request.query_params as valid json?

Comment: It's "correct". `QueryDict` generally contains a *list* of values for every key, since each key may exist more than once. And beyond this, it doesn't parse the value, it's just one string value.

Comment: I would agree if `QueryDict` "only" contained a list of values, but I don't see that restriction stated anywhere in the docs. In any event, I would like to parse this to valid Json but there doesn't appear to be a clean way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects — It contains your JSON as string, you need to parse it with `json.loads`.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely correct, you're just misunderstanding what you're looking at. A [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) internally always contains a list of values for each key, and it doesn't parse the values in any way, most certainly not as JSON. You simply need to parse it yourself:

```
import json

...

example = json.loads(request.query_params['example_param'])
```

Comment: I did try that previously. json.loads renders the value as a string (same as QueryDict) as opposed to the correct object representation. I know I'm missing something, I just can't see what.

Comment: What does that mean, “json.loads renders the value as a string”‽

Comment: I mean, json.loads(request.query_params) is actually parsing json.loads(<QueryDict: {'example_param': ['[{"id":"f8", "example_action": "kill"}]']}>) and hence returns a json object {'example_param': ['[{"id":"f8", "example_action": "kill"}]']} where the value is a string as opposed to the object representation.

Comment: Yeah, you can't JSON-parse `request.query_params`, because it's an object an not a JSON string. That's also not what I'm suggesting in my answer.